# Cannot Login RDC: An authentication error has occurred (Code: 0x8007001f)

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure, rdc

I signed up with Azure and fired up a couple of Windows Server 2012 VMs.

As I'm signed up with my Microsoft account and it automatically created a user “karl” (my first name) with my MS account password.  All cool.

In the Azure web console you can create RDP connection and download and use - all fine works well.

Now I want to let some developers in so I don’t want to give them my password.  So I go to Manage… Create a user “developer” – no domain here, just local account,  give it a password, admin group etc.

When I try to connect as the developer account from my home I get:

```
An authentication error has occurred (Code: 0x8007001f)
```

Since I'd "deleted" the Karl login, I had to re-enter my Microsoft Account details - "karl" and now that doesn't work!

I googled everywhere - Azure want $30 a month support (minimum 6 months!), so thats a No too.

I tried all forms of username/domain combination:

```
karl
.\karl
\karl
MicrosoftAccount\karl
\mymsemail@outlook.com
```

etc etc.  none work.

I then when to the web console again and downloaded the .rdp file - that doesn't work either!

Luckily I did this on my laptop and I still have a saved connection on the destop machine that I can get in with.  And I installed tightVNC as a backup to be able to get in and get the stuff off if there is another cock-up.

Then I tried logging into the other machine on the AZure virtual lan and connecting RDC from that one.  And it works!  So maybe is a port or some other issue.  The machines are standalone - no domain involved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try hostname\karl where hostname is the name you gave your VM when you created it (it is also visible on Portal). Also the default RDP port for your Vm may not be 3389 so while connecting you would have to use the syntax foo.cloudapp.net:portnumber You can get the portnumber by looking at the Endpoints for you VM in Portal.

Answer (score 1):

OK found a working solution.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941641

Essentially save out an .rdp file

Open it in Notepad, change to:

```
authentication level:i:0
```

and add line:

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
```

Now RDC works like it used to, that is.. you can actually see the remote screen and login there, rather than a modal on your own PC.

Comment: Keep in mind that by using this configuration, you have disabled Network Level Authentication (NLA,) which is a significantly less secure configuration, *especially* for RDP hosts exposed to the internet.